# i also think that this question should not have been migrated away from dsp.se

Tags: discussion

i would write an answer to this question, but do not want to register for yet another SE site.  can someone migrate this question back to DSP.SE?

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36289/c-c-library-for-changing-pitch-without-altering-formant-frequencies

here is another one that should not have been migrated:

https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36284/are-there-any-good-implementation-of-lpc-dtw-in-c

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the feedback, Robert! I was probably too trigger-happy on the migrations, but software recommendations are generally considered off-topic and had been voted as such before I migrated them.

I'm open to adding a tag something like <kbd>reference-request</kbd> where there's a possibility of someone being able to recommend a software tool (or more than one): perhaps just <kbd>software-request</kbd> as a tag?

I can't migrate them back, unfortunately.

Comment: i think in both cases, the OP wanted some code.  but it's code for a DSP alg.  and in the LPC case, i have actually posted (here) such code.

Comment: OK!  I'll lay off the migrations going forward.  Feel free to add that tag (or something similar) if you feel the questions can be answered within the scope of SP.SE.

Comment: i dunno, Peter, i think *some* questions **should** be migrated.  and sometimes i have answered DSP questions that got migrated over to some other list that i am signed up for.  but i just didn't wanna sign up for an SE list that i had never even heard of before today.  too many damn lists.

Comment: My two cents: I think questions asking for references to known, good algorithms should be on-topic, even when also asking for pointers to reference implementations. Questions asking for a library, on the other hand, should be off-topic. The difference is the focus on the algorithms vs the focus on black-box solutions.

Comment: @MBaz ok! If you notice such a question, please tag it appropriately with a new tag. <kbd>reference-implementation</kbd>?

Comment: Sounds good! Will do.